# How can I download a specific playlist from iTunes Match to an iOS 5 device?

Tags: itunes-match

Is there a way to instruct an iOS 5 device to download from iTunes Match an entire playlist or an entire album, so that it will be available offline?

Use case:

There are 1022 songs in the [SXSW 2010 Showcasing Artists](http://www.sxswtorrent.com/2010) collection and 1161 in the [SXSW 2011 Showcasing Artists](http://www.sxswtorrent.com/2011) collection.  I expect there will be a similar number in the 2012 artist collection once it is ready.  I want to be able to listen to these wondrous collections of contemporary music when I am off the net.

At the moment the only way I see to urge my iPhone to download is to click on each individual song, and the results are flakey.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scroll to the bottom of the playlist. There is a "Download All" button with the cloud download icon. Tap and wait.

Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a way to scroll to the bottom in one gesture, so if the playlist is long, you'll have to repeatedly swipe until you reach the bottom.